# Pass param to object's method in Blaze template

Tags: templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

I wanted to do something like that:

```
Template.main.helpers({
  item: function() {
    return {
      title: 'Title',
      method: function(param) {
        return param.toUpperCase();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

and the template:

```
<template name="main">
  <div>{{item.title}}</div>
  <div>{{item.method "some text to upper case"}}</div>
</template>
```

Unfortunately I get error `Can't call non-function: undefined`. It's strange that I can call object's method everything is ok, but when I try to pass param to it it throws error.

Of course I could create some helper that would take my object and call method with the param but it's kinda ugly workaround. Is there any way of passing params to object's methods?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using single-quotes?

```
<template name="main">
  <div>{{item.title}}</div>
  <div>{{item.method 'some text to upper case'}}</div>
</template>
```

Tbh, I've never tried using objects with helpers. Interesting thought though :P